# Auto send email based on the time and email address in database

Tags: php, sql

I have some user email and expiry date in my SQL database.
I have to send the users a warning email based on the expiry date.
But I don't want to keep refreshing the webpage to send the email.
How to do this even I don't open my webpage?
My webpage is usually php and html.
Is it a script or something to solve this?

Comment: Tell us some more about your webserver operating system environment, often "cron jobs" are used to handle this situation.