# How update page on server automatically while my laptop is off

Tags: php, web-scraping, refresh

I have a webpage which scrapes the data from a page and updates a database. I want it to work automatically (I mean it scrapes data from a page and updates a database) even when my laptop is off and I am not browsing the that page. Rest of the page will pick the data from database from now. Question is how and which function I should write which will run the page let it scrape the data and store it into database. Please help me; it is in php for the website.

Comment: I don't even know how to respond to this.

Comment: Maybe you can use cron on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Host your website so that it is up 24/7 and write timers and event handlers in php Google for them you will find tons of concepts and code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440834/auto-send-email-based-on-the-time-and-email-address-in-database?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: cron jobs is solution of mine quesion

Answer (score 0):

Runwhen or Cronjobs could helo you.

For runwhen checkout the website: http://code.dogmap.org/runwhen/
You create a shell-script (or something else) which is called by runwhen every X minutes. For examples see the website.

Crontabs are supported on every system.

But the question is confusing ...

Comment: you can see at as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440834/auto-send-email-based-on-the-time-and-email-address-in-database?answertab=votes#tab-top